# F# generic type constricted to specific type?

Tags: generics, functional-programming, f#

F# forces my unspecifed type to be a bool.

I needed a combination of List.find and List.tryPick, and made the function below.
Efficiancy is not important.

What did i do wrong for type 'T to only be able to be type bool?

```
let FindPickCombi(list : 'T list, func : 'T -> 'U option) : bool * ('U option) =
    (List.find 
        (fun (x : 'T) -> 
            match func(x) with
            | Some _ -> true
            | _ -> false
        ) list,
    List.tryPick(fun x -> func(x)) list)
```

Comment: The big question for my is why. The described function doesn’t make any sense to me. 

Anyway not so important.

Comment: @user198, from reading his answer, I think he wants a function that returns an item from the given list (`tryFind`-style), *and* returns a mapping over that list (`tryPick`-style).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current solution in your own answer loops twice over the whole list. Also, the first part with `List.find` will fail with a `KeyNotFoundException` if nothing is found, meaning that the `tryPick` will never return `None`.

Here's an alternative, which returns both the original type of the `list` and the mapped typed from your `func`. We wrap the whole tuple in an `option`.

```
let FindPickCombi(list : 'T list, func : 'T -> 'U option) : ('T * 'U) option =
    List.tryPick(fun x -> 
        match func x with
        | Some y -> Some(x, y)
        | None -> None) list
```

This can be further improved by ditching the `(list, func)` tuple, so that our function can use currying / partial application, which further simplifies the code and uses the same order of arguments as F#'s build-in functions (that is: the function-argument comes first).

As you can see here, we don't have the `list` argument anymore, because that is curried from `List.tryPick` automatically by F#:

```
let FindPickCombi func =
    List.tryPick(fun x -> 
        match func x with
        | Some y -> Some(x, y)
        | None -> None)
```

Using it in FSI:

```
> [1..10] |> FindPickCombi (fun x -> if x = 3 then Some "hello" else None);;
val it: (int * string) option = Some (3, "hello")
```

> What did i do wrong for type 'T to only be able to be type bool?

You made the return type of your function `bool * 'U option`, which is why the compiler forces the result of `List.find` to be a bool, which makes the type of `'T list` a list of bools.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. The return type shouldn't have been bool.

Changed function to:

```
let FindPickCombi(list : 'T list, func : 'T -> 'U option) : 'T * ('U option) =
    (List.find 
        (fun (x) -> 
            match func(x) with
            | Some _ -> true
            | _ -> false
        ) list,
    List.tryPick(fun x -> func(x)) list)
```

Comment: You loop twice over the list here and the first `List.find` will raise an exception if nothing is found, so `tryPick` doesn't _try_ anything, it'll never return `None`.